# builder syntax for collections in Kotlin

Tags: collections, kotlin, builder

I'm booting up on Kotlin and looking to configure an `Array` of `Label`s in the pattern of a builder syntax.  I came up with the Kotlin standard library function (`apply`) combined with a helper function on collections (`forEach`).  Is it correct to refer to this as builder pattern? What that means to me is that the declaration, assignment and the configuration are done in one line/step. I appreciate any thoughts about how to write this in a still more compact and clear "Kotlin-ish" way, or is this the preferred Kotlin syntax more or less.  BTW, there are a lot of ways to get this wrong (use `let` instead of `apply` does not return the receiver).

```
val labels = arrayOf(Label("A"),Label("B"),Label("C"),Label("D")).apply {
    this.forEach { it.prefWidth = 50.0 }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is a perfectly good use of these functions in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I'd suggest is avoiding repeating the word `Label` in your idiom:

```
val labels = arrayOf("A", "B", "C", "D")
        .map { Label(it).apply { prefWidth = 50.0 } }
        .toTypedArray()
```

This creates a bit more transient objects, but it reduces the noise and makes it easier to see the thing that varies between your labels.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  The intent is to create the`Array<Label>` from an `Array<String>` and then uniformly modify the width parameter.  If I stuck with `List` in all cases, I suppose that would eliminate the last line of this answer or better yet, allow `.onEach`. However,  I later use the spread operator that only works on the array.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the explicit `forEach`, you can use a `map` with an inner `apply`, which was already correctly chosen in the original post:

```
arrayOf(Label("A"), Label("B"), Label("C"), Label("D"))
    .map { it.apply { prefWidth = 50.0 } }
```

Using `apply` in these cases is perfectly valid and even defined as an **idiom** [here (Builder-style usage of methods that return Unit)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#builder-style-usage-of-methods-that-return-unit).

The shown code looks more readable to me although it creates a copy of the array inside `map`. In memory/performance critical situations, you might not want to pay this price and go with your already suggested solution instead.

---

As an other alternative, which might be useful if such actions are often needed in your code base, a simple extension function will help:

```
inline fun <T> Array<T>.applyEach(action: T.() -> Unit) = apply { forEach { it.action() } }

//usage
val labels = arrayOf(Label("A"), Label("B"), Label("C"), Label("D")).applyEach { prefWidth = 50.0 }
```

Comment: The problem with `map()` is that it will create a copy of the original array. While it's not a real problem when the array has 4 elements, it won't scale. `forEach()` will just traverse the original array and apply a block to each element.

Comment: It won’t scale? Come on, this is hair-splitting in such a scenario

Comment: There's also onEach (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/on-each.html) which you could use.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not defined on `Array`, also it takes a normal lambda, i.e. you'd need to use `it.prefWidth=50.0`

Comment: For the first answer, the map returns a `List` rather than an `Array`.  So you need to include `.toTypedArray()`.   Also too bad `onEach` is not available for `Array`. @s1m0nw1 has the idea of extension function, if the standard library function doesn't solve the problem, create your own.  I like that.

Answer (score 2):

Functions inside `Standard.kt` are indeed confusing, but you're using `apply()` correctly: it's best applied when initializing a variable. You can totally refer to this as the Builder pattern, since it provides a clean solution for constructing an instance of a class.